# Error in line where ChatBot() function is invoked

Tags: python, chatterbot

After installing the chatterbot module by using pip with the following command:
`pip install chatterbot --user`

I attempt to run following commands in the python shell

```
>>> import chatterbot
>>> from chatterbot import ChatBot
>>> x=ChatBot("Bot")



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatterbot/utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/storage_adapter.py", line 23, in __init__
    'tagger_language', languages.ENG
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 27, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 139, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I do not know how this error arises. It would be highly appreciated if someone could suggest a quick fix to get rid  of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `from chatterbot.chatterbot import ChatBot` This worked for me !!! For more check [docs](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)